# Reading nested array and display items using React

Tags: reactjs

I was unable to populate the

with the correct array information. This is now working with the fix below.

Here is the corrected file.

```
renderComments(){
  if (this.props.selectedDish != null) {
    const commentList = this.props.selectedDish.comments;
     return (
        <div>
          <h4>Comments</h4>
          {commentList.map((comment) => {
            return (
              <ul className="list-unstyled" >
                <li>
                  <p>{comment.comment}</p> 
                  <p> -- {comment.author}{" "}
                  {Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US",{
                  month: "short",
                  day: "2-digit",
                  year: "numeric"}).format(new Date(comment.date))}
                  </p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            );
          })};
        </div>  
     );
  } else {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you sava128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign comments like you did with `dish.name and dish.description`
try:

```
renderComments() {
  const dish = this.props.selectedDish;
  if (dish) {
    const commentList = dish.comments;
    console.log("test2", commentList);
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
          {commentList.map((comment) => {
            return (
              // list items here
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  } // else here
}
```

Comment: I added the .comments to the const commentList = ... and i get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined

Comment: What does ```Object.entries(this.props.selectedDish)``` returns? @Flexxall

Comment: "(8) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["id", 3]
1: (2) ["name", "ElaiCheese Cake"]
2: (2) ["image", "assets/images/elaicheesecake.png"]
3: (2) ["category", "dessert"]
4: (2) ["label", ""]
5: (2) ["price", "2.99"]
6: (2) ["description", "A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cak…am cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms"]
7: (2) ["comments", Array(5)]
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)"

Comment: I've modified the answer a bit, try that.

Comment: That is getting further. It is displaying the info like comment.author will show author for all 5 comments can i place a function in there to loop through them to separate them out

Comment: What do you mean by separating them out?

Comment: I was just linsting the items incorrectly. I have correct this and it works great.Thank you so much for the help !@!@!

Comment: ok almost working properly. when i choose a new item in the onclick event that is populating the array item to list. the comments are not lineing up with the correct selection. where do i designate the id of the comment being listed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231714/discussion-between-sava128-and-flexxall).